# Automatically update the markup of a rich text field in a publishing article page

Tags: html, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have a Sharepoint 2010 site that has a manual in it, that I'd like to write with the RichHtmlField. I'd like every h1 heading to be enclosed by an anchor such that I get something like

```
<a name="_section_1"><h1>This is my heading for section 1</h1></a>
```

I'd like it such that a office user can do this simply enough. What's the easiest way to go about this? I tried using the ItemUpdated event receiver to modify the markup after the user updates it, but this seems like a pretty dodgy and problemmatic way of going about it. Could there be an easier way to do all of this? Perhaps by adding custom markup or style to the ribbon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend using javascript (jQuery) to alter the elements once the page has been rendered. It would look something like this ([reference](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/)):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var counter = 1;
    $(h1).wrap(function(){
        var name = "_section_" + counter;
        return "<a name='" + name + "' /a>"
    });
});
</script>
```